# Wizard in Visual C++ 2005

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, wizard, visual-c++-2005

I'm trying to put together a wizard for one of my new applications. I have been searching the web for a decent tutorial but I am having no luck. I've tried [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this website](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/devstudio_macros/customappwizards/article.php/c12775) but neither have worked for me. Does any one know a good place to start from? I am using Visual C++ 2005 and using .NET . I want to create a wizard that will follow the structure of the following:

- Enter Name (edit box)
- Are You Sure you want to name it this (confirmation)
- Enter Parts (two list boxes where you can add and remove from one and another
- Are you sure you have added all the parts (confirmation box)

Sorry if that's poorly explained, I will gladly try and clarify any extra details needed, I just need a good starting point basically. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First tutorial is for win32 project, so not .NET, and second one is for C#/VB.net.

I'd start with the second one, since it's for .NET, but you have to translate c# code to C++/CLI, which may be difficult if you're new to C++/CLI.

Comment: Okay thanks I will give it a bash. I am a massive newbie to C++ so if you can offer me any advice I'd be extremely grateful, if not thanks for your help.

Comment: Start with some simpler project, and follow good tutorials (search for it here). Come back with questions :)

Comment: @bigbaz34 : As a newbie to C++, the first thing you should realize is that only the first tutorial is relevant to C++; the second tutorial is .Net specific, which means you'll have to use C++/CLI rather than C++ -- two completely separate languages. I.e., if your goal is to learn/use C++, then the second tutorial is a non-option.